# Navigation Bar from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i had soulation .i want to make navigation bar with items i will select them as (category,Product,....) So i made stored to get them throught paramater will pass it,s value from query string 
as.

```
ALTER    Proc Navcategory
(
@Category_Id  Int 
)
As
Select Distinct   Categories.Category,Categories.Category_Id

 From Categories
Where Category_Id=@Category_Id
```

and i mentioned in cs
as

```
if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null)
        {

        Banar.ImageUrl = "Handlers/Banner.ashx?Category_Id=" + Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] + "";
        using
    (SqlConnection conn = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Navcategory";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Category_Id", Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                LblNavigaton.Visible = true;
                LblNavigaton.Text = dr["Category"].ToString();

            }

        }
    }
```

so the result will be ex.
Fridge> (Category when querstring(category_Id))
4Door> (Product when querystring (Product_Id))

But I want the  result 
fridge>4Door>...>....

Comment: I suggest you try to rearrange your question, so people will can read more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried more and I solved this problem with site map provider